# How to change character-encoding of GIT commits in Webstorm for Mac

Tags: git, macos, character-encoding, terminal, webstorm

I have a small problem with git-commit-messages in Webstorm (Mac OS).
When I'm writing

```
git commit
```

some terminal-text-editor opens (I'm no expert, but apparently it's one that saves with ctrl-s and exits with ctrl-c)

However this editor doesn't seem to encode e.g. umlauts (äöü) correctly (getting weird symbols there).

My problem is, that I don't understand entirely what's happening there, and where/how I could change the character-encoding.

Is the problem related to Webstorm? To GIT? To the terminal? To the editor used by "git commit"? And how could I change it?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you writing 'git commit'? Please attach a screenshot